# Three.js object returns wrong values for position/rotation/scale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

I'm having a three.js object in my scene, which you can rotate/scale/move with the THREE.TransformControls. After positioning the object in the scene, the values of rotation/position/scale should be saved. I'm getting the values like this :

```js
// Position
$scope.scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
position.getPositionFromMatrix( $scope.object.matrixWorld );

// Rotation
var rotation = new THREE.Euler();
$scope.object.getWorldRotation(rotation);

// Size
var size = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject($scope.object);
var x = (size.max.x - size.min.x);
var y = (size.max.y - size.min.y);
var z = (size.max.z - size.min.z);
```

So, when I'm saving the values and reload the scene with the new values, the object looks really different than it should. So, I think, the functions deliver the wrong values for rotation/scale/position. For example, the size.z variable should always be 0, but when saving (and printing the value in the console) it gets an other value.

Does anyone have an idea why ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three.js offers a matrix decomposition function: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Matrix4.decompose

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
var translation = new THREE.Vector3();
var rotationQ = new THREE.Quaternion();
var scale = new THREE.Vector3();

myObject.matrixWorld.decompose(translation, rotationQ, scale);
```

Then if you want to save the rotation as an Euler:

```
var rotationE = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(rotationQ.normalize());
```

three.js r88